# Recursive function for insertion in Binary Search Tree ( C++ )

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert a new node into BST using recursion.
But I am losing the links after inserting.
An In-Order traversal showed that the program is able to access only the root node.
Here's my program

**class for BST**

```
 class bst
     {
       struct node
        {
          struct node *lchild;
          int info;
          struct node *rchild;  
        }*start;
   public:
    bst();
    void insert(int num,struct node *start);
    void search(int num,struct node *start);
    void display();
    void inorder(node *start);
    struct node *getRoot(){
    return start;
   }
};
```

**Insertion Function**

```
 void bst :: insert(int num,struct node *ptr)
    {
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        ptr = new node;
        ptr->info = num;
        ptr->lchild = NULL;
        ptr->rchild = NULL;     
       if(start == NULL)
         start = ptr;
       return;
    }
    else if(num < ptr->info)
     {
        insert(num,ptr->lchild);
     }
     else if(num > ptr->info)
     {
        insert(num,ptr->rchild);
     }
    else
    {
       cout << "Duplicate element \n";
       return;
    }
   }
```

**main function**

```
int main()
{
    bst S;
    int option,key;
    cout << "Enter an element\n";
    cin >> key;
    S.insert(key,S.getRoot());
}
```

How can i maintain proper links without changing return type of the insert function ?

Comment: Your Node struct could really use a constructor.

Comment: @Borgleader i am sorry i did not understand.

Comment: @Rustam `getRoot()` function is defined in the class itself.

Comment: Don't understand the downvoting.If the person who downvoted can answer the question, that would be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `start` initialized to `NULL` somewhere?

Also, when `start` is not `NULL`, you never link your newly created node into the tree:

```
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    ptr = new node;
    ptr->info = num;
    ptr->lchild = NULL;
    ptr->rchild = NULL;     
   if(start == NULL)
     start = ptr;
   return;
}
```

You should check if a node's child is `NULL` and then link the new node in there.  I think you are taking your recursion one level too far.

Comment: yes `start` is initialized to `NULL` using the constructor
`bst()`. And what you said is right, i am not linking the newly created node.I want to know how to do this.

Comment: can you please show me the correct code for maintaining the links

Answer (score 0):

initialize your `start` to `NULL` here

```
    bst()
    {
        start=NULL;
    }
```

Comment: I did that in the constructor.
I just did not put that in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass root by reference.

**Main Function**

```
S.insert(key,&S.getRoot());
```

**Insertion Function**

```
void bst :: insert(int num,struct node **ptr)
{
    if(*ptr == NULL)
    {
        *ptr = new node;
        (*ptr)->info = num;
        (*ptr)->lchild = NULL;
        (*ptr)->rchild = NULL;     
       //if(start == NULL)      //No need for this statement
       //  start = *ptr;        //No need for this statement
       return;
    }
    else if(num < *ptr->info)
     {
        insert(num,&((*ptr)->lchild));
     }
     else if(num > *ptr->info)
     {
        insert(num,&((*ptr)->rchild));
     }
    else
    {
       cout << "Duplicate element \n";
       return;
    }
}
```